# MongoDB Spring Batch job using Gradle

Tags: spring, mongodb, gradle, spring-batch

I want to create an item reader, writer and processor for a Spring batch job using Gradle. I am having trouble with a few things. The `delimited()` portion is giving me an error. I am trying to read two fields for now: `rxFname`, `rxLname`.

Here is my code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class PaymentPortalJob {
    private static final Logger LOG = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(PaymentPortalJob.class);


    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;


    @Bean
    MongoItemReader <PaymentAudit> fileReader(){
        return new MongoItemReaderBuilder <PaymentAudit>()
                .name("file-reader")
                .targetType(PaymentAudit.class)
                .delimited().delimiter(",").names(new String [] {"rxFname" , "rxLname"})
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<PaymentAudit, PaymentAudit> processor() {
        return new PaymentAuditItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<PaymentAudit> writer() {
         return  new MongoItemWriterBuilder()<PaymentAudit>();
         try {
             writer.setTemplate(mongoTemplate());
         }catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error(e.toString());
         }
         writer.setCollection("paymentAudit");
         return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    Job job (JobBuilderFactory jbf,
            StepBuilderFactory sbf, 
            ItemReader<? extends PaymentAudit> ir, 
            ItemWriter<? super PaymentAudit> iw) {

        Step s1 = sbf.get("file-db")
                .<PaymentAudit, PaymentAudit>chunk(100)
                .reader(ir)
                .writer(iw)
                .build();

        return jbf.get("etl")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(s1)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "db-name");
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
        return mongoTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: "The delimited() portion is giving me an error." : what error ? and you should provide minium information like :  version of libraries used (Spring  Batch, Gradle, at least)

Comment: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/builder/MongoItemReaderBuilder.html   : there is no method `delimited` nor `delimiter` exposed on this builder class: do you import custom library that would extend this base Builder class?

Comment: your code does not compile, unless `MongoItemReaderBuilder` is coming from another framework/library other than Spring Batch. There is no such method "delimited()" on the `MongoItemReaderBuilder`